# PHP - Executing ffmpeg using exec() and shell_exec() does nothing

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, audio-converter

I'm trying to convert an audio file in PHP using ffmpeg, I get the audio file via post as a m4a and I want to turn it into mp3. I do the following to do this:

```
$commandOutput = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$filePath.' -ar 8000 -ab 16000 '.str_replace('m4a', 'mp3', $filePath));
```

Yet it does nothing, and commandOutput also contains nothing. The file is saved properly but not converted to mp3, when I run the same command in terminal it converts the file properly. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but this might be something to do with PHP (or Apache) running in a chroot jail. If it is, you probably won't have the ability to call certain executables or write to certain file paths.

Comment: Any way around that? This conversion is crucial to my app.

Comment: See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping commands like this:

```
exec($cmd." 2>&1", $out, $ret);
if ($ret){
    echo "There was a problem!\n";
    print_r($out);
}else{
    echo "Everything went better than expected!\n";
}
```

`exec()` lets you capture all output and get the exit code. Adding `2>&1` makes sure to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` so you can see any error messages.

Comment: Ok, this revealed the problem I got this output: sh: ffmpeg: command not found

Comment: 1) use the full path to ffmpeg: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` or whatever

Comment: 2) set your PATH ENV variable from php first: `putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin");`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ffmpeg-php extension: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/